# Add 'Next Available AD Computer' to power-shell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently, I'm trying to add a function to my powershell script with the following goal:

On a computer that isn't added to the domain (yet), have it search a local AD server (Not azure) for the next available name based off the user's input.

I have tried and failed to use arrays in the past, and I want to use the Get-ADComputer cmdlet in this, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
$usrinput = Read-Host 'The current PC name is $pcname , would you like to rename it? (Y/N)'
if($usrinput -like "*Y*") {
    Write-Output ""
    $global:pcname = Read-Host "Please enter the desired PC Name"
    Write-Output ""

    $userinput = Read-Host "You've entered $pcname, is this correct? (Y/N)"
    if($usrinput -like "*N*") {
    GenName
    #name of the parent function
}
Write-Output ""
```

The above code is part of a larger script that parses a computer name and assigns it to the correct OU in the end.

Our naming scheme works like this: BTS-ONE-LAP-000

So it is: Department - Location - Device Type - Device Count

The code will then take the first part "BTS-ONE" and parse it for the correct OU it should go to, and then assign it using the Add-Computer cmdlet. It will also rename the machine to whatever the user typed in ($pcname).

So, before it parses the name, I'd like it to search all current names in AD.

So, the user can type in: "BTS-ONE-LAP" and it will automatically find the next available Device Count, and add it to the name. So, it will automatically generate "BTS-ONE-LAP-041".

Added Note:

I've used `Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "BTS-ONE-LAP-*"' | FT Name` and the output is

```
Name           
----           
BTS-ONE-LAP-001
BTS-ONE-LAP-002
BTS-ONE-LAP-006
BTS-ONE-LAP-007
BTS-ONE-LAP-009
BTS-ONE-LAP-010
BTS-ONE-LAP-022
BTS-ONE-LAP-024
BTS-ONE-LAP-025
BTS-ONE-LAP-028
BTS-ONE-LAP-029
BTS-ONE-LAP-030
BTS-ONE-LAP-031
BTS-ONE-LAP-032
BTS-ONE-LAP-034
BTS-ONE-LAP-035
BTS-ONE-LAP-036
BTS-ONE-LAP-037
BTS-ONE-LAP-038
BTS-ONE-LAP-039
BTS-ONE-LAP-040
BTS-ONE-LAP-041
BTS-ONE-LAP-050
BTS-ONE-LAP-051
```

I don't know how to parse this so the code knows that BTS-ONE-LAP-003 is available (I'm terrible with arrays).

Comment: You will probably find the `-filter` parameter to `Get-ADComputer` to be useful.

Comment: @Jeff While that works, it seems to output an Array, and quite honestly, i'm terrible with Arrays. I've never been able to get them to work properly.

Comment: If you can't handle that sort of basic operation, you're not going to get a viable solution. Your alternative will be to try to retrieve each individual number one at a time until the call to `Get-ADComputer` fails. That's a _really_ _bad_ way to do it, and it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Also, DO NOT use `Format-*` cmdlets for output if you want to parse data further. PowerShell generates _objects_, not _text_, and when you have objects, you can inspect properties of them, and manipulate the entire object after inspecting.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, and I need something that scales. How should I properly format a foreach() statement to parse this?

Comment: So.. don't use "BTS-ONE-LAP-*"' ?

Comment: I don't think you actually need a `ForEach()`; all you need to do is look at the last item in a sorted list.

Comment: the `Sort-Object` cmdlet will sort those names neatly. grab the last one and add one to the suffix.

Comment: Using `"BTS-ONE-LAP-*"` appears to be the correct filter pattern, but `ForEach` is designed to process each item in a list/array. You don't need to do that; you just need to look at the last element after sorting.

Comment: Try `(Get-ADComputer ... | Sort-Object Name)[-1]`

Comment: Ok, `((Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "BTS-ONE-LAP-*"' | Sort-Object Name)[-1]) | FT Name]` returns BTS-ONE-LAP-051, not -003..

Comment: While this method allows me to find the last name used, I want to find the first available name. In this case it's BTS-ONE-LAP-003, not BTS-ONE-LAP-051.

I'm trying to get it so it will tell the script that -003 is available, but I genuinely do not know how.

Comment: I figured it out. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "BTS-ONE-LAP-*"' | Sort-Object Name[-1])

$i = 1
$found = $false
Foreach($Name in $list.Name)
{
    while($i -eq [int]$Name.Split("-")[3].Split("-")[0])
    {
        $i++
    }
}
$i
```

The above code will go through each name in the list, and will stop when it discovers say the 3rd computer in the set is NOT computer #3.

Example:

```
BTS-ONE-LAP-001 | $i = 1
BTS-ONE-LAP-002 | $i = 2
BTS-ONE-LAP-006 | $i = 3
```

It split BTS-ONE-LAP-006 to be 006, and convert it to an integer, making it 6.
Since 6 does not equal 3, we know that BTS-ONE-LAP-003 is available.

Comment: When comparing two integer values, I wouldn't use the (string) Regex `-match` operator. `-eq` should be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to create a reusable function like below:

```
function Find-FirstAvailableNumber ([int[]]$Numbers, [int]$Start = 1) {
    $Numbers | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
        if ($Start -ne $_) { return $Start }
        $Start++
    }
    # no gap found, return the next highest value
    return $Start
}

# create an array of integer values taken from the computer names
# and use the helper function to find the first available number
$numbers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "BTS-ONE-LAP-*"') | 
            ForEach-Object { [int](([regex]'(\d+$)').Match($_.Name).Groups[1].Value) }

# find the first available number or the next highest if there was no gap
$newNumber = Find-FirstAvailableNumber $numbers

# create the new computername using that number, formatted with leading zero's
$newComputerName = 'BTS-ONE-LAP-{0:000}' -f $newNumber
```

Using your example list, `$newComputerName` would become `BTS-ONE-LAP-003`

<sup>Note that not everything a user might type in with `Read-Host` is a valid computer name. You should add some checks to see if the proposed name is acceptable or skip the proposed name alltogehter, since all your machines are named 'BTS-ONE-LAP-XXX'.

See [Naming conventions in Active Directory for computers, domains, sites, and OUs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this was actually part of a reusable function already (trimmed it down to the bit that wasn't working), but I've made some modification based off your recommendation. Thanks!